# "Ich fing an zu weinen" vs. "Ich fing zu weinen an" - was ist besser?

Tags: sentence-structure

Schon 2 Jahre glaube ich, dass man nur *„ich fing an, zu weinen“* sagen kann. Aber neulich habe ich es anders formuliert gesehen, nämlich in einem Buch bei Wattpad, und da war diese Konstruktion verwendet: *„ich fing zu weinen an.“*

Und meine Frage ist, welches ist richtig, und wenn beides, dann welches klingt besser?

Answer (score 12):

Beides ist möglich und mir kommt auch keine der beiden Varianten *besser* oder *geläufiger* vor. Allerdings gilt dies nur für diese einfache Form. Sobald weitere Elemente dazukommen, gibt es feine Bedeutungsunterschiede.

> Sie fing in ihrem Zimmer zu weinen an.

Sie war in ihrem Zimmer und fing dort an zu weinen.

> Sie fing an, in ihrem Zimmer zu weinen.

Sie entwickelte die Gewohnheit, in ihrem Zimmer zu weinen.

Das Adverbial *in ihrem Zimmer* kann entweder an das Verb *anfangen* oder an das Verb *weinen* gebunden sein. Die erste Variante erlaubt prinzipiell beides, da die zweite Variante wegen des Nebensatzes aber nur die Bindung an *weinen* erlaubt, wird man der ersten Variante die gegenteilige Bedeutung zuordnen.

> Sie fing in ihrem Zimmer an(,) zu weinen.

Diese dritte Variante ist wieder eindeutig: Sie war in ihrem Zimmer und fing dort an zu weinen.